# Regexp and grouping

Tags: regex, perl

I have an regex to match string of the form x=y. Ie name assigned a value. The value can optionally be quoted and both name and value conform to \w+

My regex is

```
\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+'
```

There can be multiple of these assignments on one line, but here I ran into problems. For some reason when I enclose this regex in (?:) it won't match. See test case below

```
use Test::More;

my $re1 = qr/^\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+'$/p;
my $re2 = qr/^(?:\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+')$/p;

ok('xy="abc"' =~ $re1);

say "PREMATCH ${^PREMATCH}";
say "MATCH ${^MATCH}";
say "POSTMATCH ${^POSTMATCH}";


ok('xy="abc"' =~ $re2);

done_testing;
```

Output is

```
ok 1
PREMATCH xy=
MATCH "abc"
POSTMATCH
not ok 2
#   Failed test at ./test.pl line 20.
1..2
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

I don't understand why the first matches and the second not. And I also don't understand why the first one matches only the part after the equal sign.

Comment: Are you trying to match both `xy` and `"abc"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
^\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+'$
```

is equivalent to

```
(?:^\w+=\w+)|(?:"\w+")|(?:'\w+'$)
```

where it matches the `^` followed by whitespace OR quotation marks around the word OR a single-quote around words that occur at the end of the string.

Your

```
^(?:\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+')$
```

Requires that ALL of those within the group start at the beginning of the line (due to the `^` outside of the group), then the various test, and then ALL of those groups must complete at the end of the string (due to the `$` outside of the group).

The simplest fix is to simply move both the `^` and `$` into to the group:

```
(?:^\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+'$)
```

Comment: Isn't `^` only part of the first choice for the alternation?

Comment: In the case of $re1, `^` is part of the first alternation choice. When the `(?:...)` group is encountered in $re2, the `^` was moved outside of the alternation which I would assume caused some of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are having an issue with your alternation.  It is taking the entire part of the regex before the first pipe as one option.  In other words,

```
/^\w+=\w+|"\w+"|'\w+'$/
```

is parsed into three possibilities to match

```
^\w+=\w+
"\w+"
```

or

```
'\w+'$
```

To fix this you have 2 choices (that I see).  First expand each of those choices to what you really want:

```
/^\w+=\w+|^\w+="\w+"|^\w+='\w+'$/
```

The second is to cluster the alternation:

```
/^\w+=(?:\w+|"\w+"|'\w+')$/
```